# How to implement a Django server-side application that treats a database as a queue

Tags: database, django, queue

Assume I have 100 records in my database and I want to apply a method on 5 of the records every minute. Is it possible to treat the database as a queue so that after the first 5 records will apply the method, they'll get pushed to the bottom of the database, and the second quintet will be pushed to be the first quintet and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a background processor/task queue such as [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Basically you'd setup a task that would run every 5 minutes. Then in that task you'd pull the 5 records you want to edit. A good way to do this is to have a datetime on the model that gets updated on every save using the `auto_now` parameter for `DateTimeField`.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. But I don't get one thing, if I use the `DateTimeField` method you suggested, wouldn't I have tho scan the whole database every 5 minutes to find the records with the largest delta between `CurrentTime` and their `DateTimeField`?

Comment: You could put an index on it and get the oldest date. That way it's not a comparison and the data should be available pretty early on in the search, no? Edit: in your original question you said you'd only have 100 items. That's not going to cause any performance problems. I'm guessing the actual application is a bit larger though.